# Check if route exists

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to redirect requests to `/work/:product` to a component only if product exists in my JSON file. Currently I have the following:

```
<Route path="/work/:product"render={props => (check_that_product_exiists) ? <Life sayHello = { this.sayHello } />:<Redirect to="/" />} />
```

The product names are currently in a JSON file that has this schema:

```
[
    {
        "name":"adcall",
        ...
    },
    ...
]
```

How can I check that the placeholder product is in one of the elements of that nested JSON file? I am using react-router v4 (which is a bit different to prior versions).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would not do it at the Router level but at the component level. So allow the user to go through:

```
<Route
  path="/work/:product"
  render={Life}
/>
```

Then in your `Life` component you can do

```
...
componentWillMount() {
  if (isProductExisting === false)
    window.location = '/';
}
...
```

the reason why I do it in `componentWillMount` is because I want to avoid mounting a component if then I am going to redirect. Inside this component you can grab the product name from a JSON file you import, and from the path (make sure in this case to use the `withRouter` method to pass routing props to this component).